# CSS overlay div not stretching to document height

Tags: css

I have an overlay element that gets appended to the document with JavaScript. Here is its style declarations:

```
#overlay_mask {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

It's size stretches to the height of the window correctly, but when the user scrolls, the overlay doesn't follow.

The `html` and `body` elements are set to `width: 100%`; and `height: 100%`. The overlay is the first child of the document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `position:fixed;`. The overlay will still stretch to the size of your window only, but it will stay in position even if the user scrolls.

Comment: This is such an easy trick, but very useful one. This exact same overlay problem has been bothering me for some months, now it´s gone... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### To use height in percentages:

1. Set a doctype.

   ```
   <!doctype html>
   ```
2. Make sure you have given the parent and `html`, css `height` in percentage.

   ```
   html, body {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }
   ```

   > Only if the parent element has a defined height, i.e. not a value of `auto`. If that has `100%` height, the parent's parent height must be defined, too. This could go until to the `html` root element.